# jquery working in firefox but not in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

Ok i know this might sound like a duplicate question, as a lot of questions have been asked like this one...but i have looked into almost all of them and could not find what the solution.

Ok I am getting the following response from the server using normal ajax call:

```
<form id="ctl00" name="ctl00" method="post" action="RatesGrids.aspx?pt=EMPL&amp;RT=bill">
   <div>
     <input id="__VIEWSTATE" type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUENTM4MQ9kFgJmD2QWAmYPPCsADQEADxYCHgtfIUl0ZW1Db3VudAICZGQYAQUMZ3JkQmlsbFJhdGVzDzwrAAoBCAIBZE4pvNtSHIbu7h7ISmN42ktJBm5R">
   </div>
   <div>
      <table id="grdBillRates" class="tableView" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
          <thead>
             <tr class="tableViewHeader">
                <th scope="col" style="white-space:normal;">Emp. Id</th>
                <th scope="col" style="white-space:normal;">Last Name</th>
                <th scope="col" style="white-space:normal;">*Res Usage</th>
                <th scope="col" style="white-space:normal;">Source</th>
                <th scope="col" style="white-space:normal;">Eff. Date</th>
                <th scope="col" style="white-space:normal;">*Bill 1</th>
                <th scope="col" style="white-space:normal;">*Bill 2</th>
                <th class="display_none" scope="col" style="white-space:normal;"></th>
                <th class="display_none" scope="col" style="white-space:normal;">Time Stamp</th>
                <th scope="col" style="white-space:normal;">Currency</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr class="tableViewRow" onclick="loadrowitems(0,this)" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='default';">
                  <td style="width:100px;white-space:normal;">10000000034 </td>
                  <td style="width:125px;white-space:normal;">Khan</td>
                  <td style="width:125px;white-space:normal;"></td>
                  <td style="width:80px;white-space:normal;">Local</td>
                  <td style="width:80px;white-space:normal;">12/04/2012</td>
                  <td align="right" style="width:80px;white-space:normal;">3.6500</td>
                  <td align="right" style="width:80px;white-space:normal;">6.0000</td>
                  <td class="display_none" style="width:0px;white-space:normal;">Z-C$ </td>
                  <td class="display_none" style="white-space:normal;">0,0,0,0,1,107,21,255</td>
                  <td style="width:70px;white-space:normal;">Z-C$</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tableViewAlternatingRow" onclick="loadrowitems(1,this)" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='default';">
                <td style="width:100px;white-space:normal;">10000000034 </td>
                <td style="width:125px;white-space:normal;">Khan</td>
                <td style="width:125px;white-space:normal;">444 </td>
                <td style="width:80px;white-space:normal;">Local</td>
                <td style="width:80px;white-space:normal;">12/04/2012</td>
                <td align="right" style="width:80px;white-space:normal;">2.1000</td>
                <td align="right" style="width:80px;white-space:normal;">3.2000</td>
                <td class="display_none" style="width:0px;white-space:normal;">Z-C$ </td>
                <td class="display_none" style="white-space:normal;">0,0,0,0,1,107,21,254</td>
                <td style="width:70px;white-space:normal;">Z-C$</td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
   </div>
</form>
```

Now i have to append the table in response in `<div id="grdRates"></div>`.

The application i am working on was created only keeping IE in mind, so it was catered using the following code:

```
if (contents) {
    var table;
    if ($(contents).find('table').length > 0)
        table = $(contents).find('table')[0].xml
        if (table) {
            $('#grdRates').parent().show();
            $('#grdRates').html(table);
        }
}
```

above code was not working in Firefox as well as Chrome , was giving that xml as undefined and never showing the results, so i tried the following:

```
if (contents) {
   var table;
   if ($(contents).find('table').length > 0)
       if ($.browser.msie)
            table = $(contents).find('table')[0].xml
       else
            table = $(contents).find('#grdBillRates');

       if (table) {
          $('#grdRates').parent().show();
          if ($.browser.msie)
             $('#grdRates').html(table);
          else
             $('#grdRates').html(table.parent().html());     
       }
   }
}
```

Note the `#grdBillRates` is the table id in the above HTML. Now this is working fine in firefox (showing the grid fine) but i have tried almost everything for chrome, but no luck....

And one more thing i cannot change the DLL so the solution has to be using script. Any help will be appreciated guys...Thanks

Comment: "Now this was not working in Firefox as well as Chrome so i tried the following:" How was it not working? "Now this is working fine in firefox but i have tried almost everything for chrome, but no luck...." Again, how is it not working in Chrome? If we don't know what the problem is, how can we help you fix it?

Comment: Sorry @Pete, my bad for the confusion..just edited the question..the `#grdBillRates` is the table from the response and i want append/assign it to the innerHTML of `#grdRates`...hope that cleares it

Answer (score 0):

is there any error?

did you try to append it? something like this:

```
if (contents) {
   var table = $(contents).find('#grdBillRates');
   if (table.length > 0)
       $('#grdRates').parent().show().append(table);
   }
}
```

Comment: No, there are no errors, It just shows me "[object]" something instead of the table

Comment: try appending `table.html()`

Comment: @Pete, I tried everything, it just does not show up...wait let me put up some screenshots for the webkit console.